# jquery-mobile: get value of ui-li-count

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a dozen collapsible list (like the following) and each gets a bunch of dynamically created 'li's:

```
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
    <h3>Community Alerts
    <span id="comm_count" class="ui-li-count" style="float:right;">0</span></h3>
    <ul id="communityAlertList" data-role="listview"></ul>
  </div>
```

When a user does a taphold on one of the 'li's I want to delete it the 'li' (that parts working) and then I need to update/reduce the ui-li-count.  To find the span and get its content I'm using the following:

```
    var ui_li_count = $(this).closest('span')
    var count = $(ui_li_count).textContent;    // also tried innerHTML
    alert("Count = " +count);
    count--;
    $(ui_li_count).html(count);
```

The alert shows "Count = undefined".

How do I find and retrieve the textContent?

Comment: What element is $(this) ? an li within the ul?

Comment: yes, the li that received the taphold and is within the ul with the id=communityAlertList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of `.closest()`. The way `.closest()` works is to find the closest parent/child, fanning out away from the (this) element. In your code there is no span element that is a direct parent/child of an `<li>`, so it returns undefined.

To put it simply using jquery selectors, the span you want to get is nested like so from your li:

```
var count =  $(this).parent().parent().children('h3').children('span').text();
```

However we don't really want to use all those selectors, so we could just do this:

```
var count =  $(this).closest('div').find('span.ui-li-count').text();
```

Because the `h3` is on the same level as your `ul`, we first need to get it's container which in your example is a `div`. Then we use find, to find the span within that div.

Also note that i used `.text()` to get the content. This is the jQuery alternative to javascripts `.textContent`.

Made a simple test case so you can see it working with your code:

http://jsbin.com/odamac/3/edit

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction :)

---

**UPDATE**

One more problem your going to run into is that your DOM is not exactly laid out how you think it is. jQuery Mobile inserts extra elements into the page when the window loads so that it can implement it's functionality.

Your actual page DOM looks something like this:

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible">

        <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
            <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="ui-btn-text">
                        Community Alerts
                        <span id="comm_count" class="ui-li-count" style="float:right;">5</span>
                        <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ui-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                 </span>
             </a>
         </h3>

         <div class="ui-collapsible-content">

             <ul id="communityAlertList" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
                 <li data-theme="b" id="1" class="ui-li">1</li>
                 <li data-theme="b" id="2" class="ui-li">2</li>
                 <li data-theme="b" id="3" class="ui-li">3</li>
                 <li data-theme="b" id="4" class="ui-li">4</li>
                 <li data-theme="b" id="5" class="ui-li">5</li>
             </ul>

         </div>
     </div>

 </div>
```

Notice the extra  and  elements that jQuery Mobile has inserted to make the collapisible functionality work. You will need to account for these elements when traversing the DOM using `closest();`, `find();`, `parent();`, `children();`, etc.

Comment: Your answer and description makes perfect sense. However, I couldn't get your example to work in my code or on jsbin.

Comment: Hmm,  can you post your jsbin, and I will take a look?

Comment: No offence ppetree, but you seem to have completely ignored all my advice. Furthermore, you can't do `$(ui_li_count).closest()`, you should instead do `ui_li_count.closest()` as it is a javascript variable. You also need to convert the counter variable to an integer as it is a string and will return NaN. Finally you need to be more specific as to your selectors as jQuery Mobile inserts extra divs and spans into your code when it runs. I updated your jsbin so it will work http://jsbin.com/odamac/7/edit

Comment: I never did get your way (or any other jquery way) to work... I ended up adding the class to the li, retrieving the class name on taphold and updating the ui-li-count that way...  not as pretty as I'd like but it works.  Thanks for all your help!